# How to install Secret Maryo Chronicles on Ubuntu 17.10 64-bit?

Tags: 17.10, 64-bit, games

I would like to install Secret Maryo Chronicles on Ubuntu 17.10 64-bit with all music but I don't know how to.
I will appreciate some help.